# Couldn't load the external resource at: http://{IP}:{Port}/XXX

Tags: neo4j, load-csv

I have a problem with loading csv data … This is my use case : I have a MVC controller which returns CSV files. When I access “‘http://{MY IP}:8083/site’” via a browser like Chrome it returns the data I want … however when I access this from Neo4j browser it returns “Couldn't load the external resource at: ‘http://{MY IP}:8083/site “… This was working before when I was not working remotly on VPN and I have not changed anything… the only thing that comes to my mind is that I am on a VPN now… can this cause a problem?? Is this a permission issue? Log files do not say anything !!! 
These are my  Neo4j and network related configurations in neo4j.conf properties:

```
    #*****************************************************************
# Neo4j configuration
#*****************************************************************
# The name of the database to mount
#dbms.active_database=graph.db
# Paths of directories in the installation.
#dbms.directories.data=data
#dbms.directories.plugins=plugins
#dbms.directories.certificates=certificates
# This setting constrains all `LOAD CSV` import files to be under the `import` directory. Remove or uncomment it to
# allow files to be loaded from anywhere in filesystem; this introduces possible security problems. See the `LOAD CSV`
# section of the manual for details.
dbms.directories.import=import
# Whether requests to Neo4j are authenticated.
# To disable authentication, uncomment this line
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
#*****************************************************************
# Network connector configuration
#*****************************************************************

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.type=BOLT
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
# To have Bolt accept non-local connections, uncomment this line
 dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687

# HTTP Connector
dbms.connector.http.type=HTTP
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
# To accept non-local HTTP connections, uncomment this line
dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474

# HTTPS Connector
dbms.connector.https.type=HTTP
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.encryption=TLS
# To accept non-local HTTPS connection, change 'localhost' to '0.0.0.0'
dbms.connector.https.address=0.0.0.0:7473

# Number of Neo4j worker threads.
#dbms.threads.worker_count=
```

This is also set to true :

```
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
```

Comment: To confirm: are you saying that you can access that URL using Chrome while on the VPN?

Comment: Yes I can access the URL using Chrome on VPN.. the neoj4j servers are internal so I am thinking  the VPN IP range is not really in the same range with the internal IPs so something is filtering or blocking it... These are all my thoughts ... not sure if that is really the case